# Aggregate root id reference field naming convention

Tags: kotlin, domain-driven-design, naming-conventions, aggregateroot, hexagonal-architecture

Let me assume that I have the 2 aggregates as below.

```kotlin
data class Order(
    val id: OrderId,
    val shipmentIds: Set<ShipmentId>
) : BaseAggregate() {}
```

```kotlin
data class Shipment(
    val id: ShipmentId,
    var fromAddress: ShippingAddress,
    var toAddress: ShippingAddress
) {}
```

In the `Order` class, I reference a set of shipments by Aggregate root id. and I named it as `shipmentIds`.
I assume we can just name it as `shipments` rather than putting `*ids` as suffix.

Could you guys let me know there would be any potential issue with this approach?

Comment: It should be fine, although you might want to consider if introducing a Shipments type (as a replacement for Set<ShipmentId>) has favorable benefits vs cost.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason Hi thanks for your comment! I'm not sure what you mean by `shipments type`. could you explain more? :)

Comment: Notice how your example includes a specific type for OrderId? and how a Shipment is composed of a ShipmentId and two ShippingAddress?  It might also make sense to include another type for Shipments.  "Set", as far as I know, is not taken from the language of Orders and Shipping....